# Multiple jQuery actions() to happen at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want my logo to change css on click, AS WELL as fadeIn..

I have tried something like this:

```
$(".logo").fadeIn() .css({"opacity": "1.0","height": "75px"})
```

Doesnt work, as well as this:

```
$(".logo").css({"opacity": "1.0","height": "75px"}) 
$(".logo").fadeIn();
```

Comment: use jquery animate method if you have to use css

Comment: No need for JS here - use CSS `transition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with css only using `transition` property and `:active`

```css
.logo{
  background-color:yellow;
  color:red;
  padding:20px;
  transition:opacity 2s linear;
  opacity:0.3;
  }

.logo:active{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<span class="logo">Logo click me</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `animate` method along with `fadeIn`.

```js
$('.logo').click(function(){

 $('.logo').fadeIn().animate({'opacity':'1','height':'75px'}, 1500);
});
```

```css
.logo{
  opacity: 0.1;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="logo">Logo</span>
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aalind/dXCPF/105/).